# Symfony Upload with VichUploader and One to Many Associated Entities

Tags: symfony, symfony4, symfony-forms, vichuploaderbundle

This is my problem brief: I have 2 entities that are associated OneToMany relation. There is no problem when uploading first time but the update process were confused. If an update request sent that **handleRequest** function of **Form** were remove some of the relation entities and add the new upload files.

For example: I have 1 credit and 2 extra file related with that credit. Then when I want to update and upload any other file. The last file has been deleted automaticly when execute the **handleRequest** function of Form.

Here is my codebase:

**Credit** entity:

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Repository\CreditRepository")
 * @Vich\Uploadable()
 */
class Credit
{

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="App\Entity\ExtraFile", mappedBy="credit", cascade={"persist", "remove"})
     * @var ExtraFile[] An ArrayCollection of ExtraFile objects.
     */
    private $extraFiles;
```

**ExtraFile** entity:

```
/**
 * Class ExtraFile
 * @ORM\Entity()
 * @Vich\Uploadable()
 */
class ExtraFile
{

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Credit", inversedBy="extraFiles")
     */
    private $credit;
```

In my Controller:

```
public function applicationFiles(Credit $credit, Request $request): Response
{
    $form = $this->createForm(CreditExtraType::class, $credit);
    $form->handleRequest($request); // <--- At this point the $credit entity "extraFiles" entities changed and removed the last or two entities (it depent how much file send for upload) with OneToMany.
    if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
```

And the **CreditExtraType** codes:

```
class CreditExtraType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('extraFiles', CollectionType::class, [
                'entry_type' => CreditExtraVichFileType::class,
                'allow_add' => true,
                'allow_delete' => true,
                'required' => false,
                'by_reference' => false,
                'disabled' => false,
            ])
        ;

    }
```

Do you have any idea?

Comment: Could try to remove @Vich\Uploadable() anotation from Credit entity and keep the one from ExtraFile entity ?

Comment: There is another fields are uploadable that I find unnecessary to share bcs dont have any relation rest of the Credit entity.